# Java: How can I read text and numbers from a file

Tags: java, file, input

I am creating a simple program to data read from a text file. The file stores information about a person, with the name, age and a number on each line:

Eg: File format per line

```
      Francis Bacon  50    2
```

I can read in a file no problem if it is just text, but I am confused on how to differentiate between text and numbers. Here is a look at my code:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Test{

    private People people[] = new People[5];


    public Test(){
        BufferedReader input;

        input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("People.txt"));// file to be readfrom
        String fileLine;
        int i = 0;

        while (test != null){
            fileLine = input.readLine(); 

            // Confused as to how to parse this line into seperate parts and store in object:
            // eg:
            people[i].addName(fileLine - part 1);
            people[i].addBookNo(fileLine - part 2);
            people[i].addRating(fileLine - part 3)

            i++

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suggest you use the `Scanner` class instead. That class provides you with methods such as [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and so on.

You could use it to read from the file directly like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("People.txt"));

while (s.hasNext()) {
    people[i].addName(s.next());
    people[i].addBookNo(s.nextInt());
    people[i].addRating(s.nextInt());
}
```

(Just realized that you may have spaces in the name. That complicates things slightly, but I would still consider using a scanner.)

An alternative solution would be to use a regular expression and groups to parse the parts. Something like this should do:

```
(.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)
```

Comment: great. I have no experience with regexs, how exactly can I store this in a string?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex works on these 3 cases, breaking them into 3 matched groups.

Regex
    `(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)`

Cases

```
Francis Bacon  50    2
Jill St. John 20 20
St. Francis Xavier III 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in this way, you can try doing like this :

1. Fixing the way data will be present in the file, say

   firstName.lastName.age.number;
2. Then you can write code to read data upto . and store it in a variable (you will be knowing what it is meant for) and after ";" there will be second entry.